# histograms hours day (continuous bins)

Tags: matlab, histogram

I produce the histogram in the figure below (on the x-axis there are hours of the day).
Any idea how to center it around the highest value? in this case I would like to put the right part next to the left side of the first bins...

Time is a cellarray containing time stamps (1 minute resolution) of 12 days.

```
Time{1,1}='00:00:00';
Time{2,1}='00:01:00';
...
Time{1000,1}='16:39:00';
...
Time{17280,1}='23:59:00'
```

Sleeping is a vector containing 1 if the subject is sleeping 0 if not.

```
sleeping(1,1)=1;
sleeping(2,1)=1;
...
sleeping(1000,1)=0;
...
sleeping(17280,1)=1;



    figure
    hist(datenum(Time(sleeping==1)),24)
    datetick
```

[image]

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the code that generated this plot? Isn't the part on the right from the next day and therefore does not really reflect the observation of the first day?

Comment: yes it is, but it dosn't matter to which day it belongs...I am interested on the hours histogram....

Comment: You are interested in the histogram of all hours? (e.g. any 3am, any day, would be the same bin) Or you're interested in the hourly histogram for one day?  (there's an issue with your code, either way).

Comment: Call `hist` with two output arguments. Detect the maximum using `max`  with two output arguments. Then use `mod` or `circshift` to circularly shift the _x_-axis values

Comment: @nkjt I am interested in the histogram of all hours. What is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use hist to return the values (`vals`) and the bins (`bins`) of the histogram:

```
[vals, bins] = hist(datenum(Time(sleeping==1)),24);
```

then, find where the maximum actually is, in order to center the histogram with respect to the maximum:

```
[val, idx] = max(vals);
```

Then, obtain the position of the center of the histogram (it should be `12` if you use a `24`-bin histogram).  Then, estimate the amount of the shift required to move the center of the histogram to the center of the plot.

```
centerPos = round(length(bins)/2);
shiftSize = centerPos - idx;
```

After finding the `shiftSize`, we could have three cases: a) the shift is to the left, in which case the shift will be larger. I deal with that as follows:

```
if shiftSize < 0    % move to the left w.r.t. center
    shiftSize = length(bins) - shiftSize;
end
```

Also, b) if the shift is to the right, then there is no need to update `shiftSize`. Then, c) `shiftSize` is zero, which means that there is no need to shift. In this two last cases, there is no need to change `shiftSize`.

In case of a) and b), we now perform a circular shift (as @Luis Mendo suggested):

```
if shiftSize    % if it is 0 it means that it is already centered
    nvals = circshift(vals, shiftSize, 2);
    nbins = circshift(bins, shiftSize, 2);
end
```

Finally, we plot, and get the current axis to make the adjustments.

```
figure, bar(bins, nvals); ax = gca;
```

Now, you make sure you have all the bins for all 24 hours.

```
ax.XTick = bins;
```

Note here, that if you do `ax.XTick = nbins` it will give you an error because the xTick has to be monotonically incrementing.  And finally, you make those x-axis labels change for the shifted ones:

```
ax.XTickLabel = datestr(nbins, 'HH:MM');
```

Here is the complete **code** for the **example** you provided:

```
Time{1,1}='00:00:00';
Time{2,1}='00:01:00';
Time{1000,1}='16:39:00';
Time{17280,1}='23:59:00';

sleeping(1,1)=1;
sleeping(2,1)=1;
sleeping(1000,1)=0;
sleeping(17280,1)=1;

[vals, bins] = hist(datenum(Time(sleeping==1)),24);

% get the maximum
[val, idx] = max(vals);

% circularly shift to center around the maximum
centerPos = round(length(bins)/2);
shiftSize = centerPos - idx;
if shiftSize < 0    % move to the left w.r.t. center
    shiftSize = length(bins) - shiftSize;
end

if shiftSize    % if it is 0 it means that it is already centered
    nvals = circshift(vals, shiftSize, 2);
    nbins = circshift(bins, shiftSize, 2);
end

figure, bar(bins,nvals); ax = gca;
ax.XTick = bins; 
ax.XTickLabel = datestr(nbins, 'HH:MM');
```

Which gives me the following plot:

[image: Centered along the max :)]

Let me know if you have questions.